# SQL all records that covers to dates in SQL server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as the below:(date format is dd/MM/yyyy) (SQL server 2016)

```
  ID  FromDate       ToDate
  1   01/01/2018      30/01/2018
  2   02/02/2018      02/03/2018
  3   03/03/2018      03/04/2018
  4   04/04/2018      05/05/2018
```

I need to get the records that covers all the period I supply( as from-to dates).
For example if I supplied the dates **(StartDate=10/02/2018)** and **(EndDate=01/05/2018)** the query should return the records 2,3,4
since  the startDate is within the record of ID=2 and the endDate within the record of ID=4 and the rest of the dates is between the records 2,3,4/.

If there is a break in the dates then it should return nothing,for example if I supplied the dates **(StartDate=01/02/2018)** and **(EndDate=01/05/2018)**
nothing should be returned since  01/02/2018 is not covered by any dates.

Also as an another example:

```
 ID  FromDate       ToDate
  1   01/01/2018      30/01/2018
  2   02/02/2018      02/03/2018
  3   06/03/2018      03/04/2018
  4   04/04/2018      05/05/2018
```

if I supplied **(StartDate=10/02/2018)** and **(EndDate=01/05/2018)** 
should return nothing, since there is a break of dates between 02/03/2018 and 06/03/2018

Answer (score 1):

Edit: for date breaks

```
declare @t table
(id int identity,
FromDate date,
ToDate date
);

insert into @t(FromDate, ToDate)
values
('20180101', '20180201'),
('20180202', '20180302'),
('20180303', '20180403'),
('20180404', '20180505');

declare @fromdate date = '20180210',
        @todate date = '20180501';


select *
from @t
where FromDate <= @todate
  and Todate >= @fromdate;


with d
as
(
select *, lag(ToDate) over(order by FromDate) as PreviousToDate
from @t
where FromDate <= @todate
  and Todate >= @fromdate
)
select Id, FromDate, ToDate
from d
where not exists(select * from d as bd where bd.FromDate<>dateadd(day, 1, bd.PreviousToDate));
```

Comment: this is ok, but will return the records even  if there is a gap between them.

Answer (score 0):

```
create  table t
(id int identity,
FromDate date,
ToDate date
)

insert into t(FromDate, ToDate)
values
('20180101', '20180201'),
('20180202', '20180302'),
('20180303', '20180403'),
('20180404', '20180505')

declare @fromdate date = '20180210',
        @todate date = '20180501';
declare @fromdatetopick date,@todatetopick date,@idtopick int,@count int,@fromdatepick date,@todatepick date,@idpick int,@datediff int,@maxdatediff int
set @count=0
set @maxdatediff=0
declare abc cursor for

select *
from t
where FromDate >= @fromdate
  or (Todate <= @todate and Todate>=@fromdate)
   open abc
   fetch next from abc into @idtopick,@fromdatetopick,@todatetopick
   while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
   begin
   if (@count=0)
   begin 
   set @todatepick=@todatetopick
   end 
   else
   begin
   set @fromdatepick=@fromdatetopick
   set @datediff=DATEDIFF(day,@todatepick,@fromdatepick)
   if (@datediff>@maxdatediff)
   begin 
   set @maxdatediff=@datediff
   end

   end
   set @todatepick=@todatetopick
   set @count=@count+1


   fetch next from abc into @idtopick,@fromdatetopick,@todatetopick
   end
   close abc
   deallocate abc

   if (@maxdatediff>1)
   begin
      select * from t where id=null
   end 

   else
   begin
   select *
from t
where FromDate >= @fromdate
  or (Todate <= @todate and Todate>=@fromdate)  
   end
```

Comment: It almost true! however it returns the records if the start or the end date before or after the dates. but if there is a gap then it will return null, which is perfect,but how to fix the bug I mentioned?

Comment: Do you please explain about your bug?

Comment: if you set the fromDate to '20170210' ( which is before the very first date) it will return all the records

Comment: No it return null if there's gap between date. Please vote if you find helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(todate) over (order by fromdate) as prev_todate
      from t
     ) t
where fromdate < @todate and
      todate > @fromdate and
      (prev_todate is null and fromdate = @fromdate or
       prev_todate = dateadd(day, -1, fromdate)
     );
```

Note that this handles the situation where the dates start on your desired `fromdate`.